# Firebase Authentication redirect when logged in with express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app I have an admin control panel that only allows admis to access. Here's the code.

```
app.get('/acp', function (req, res) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {
        // Logged in
        res.send('Hello world');
    } else {
        // Not logged in
        res.redirect('/admin');
    }
});
```

But when the user is not logged in, he'll be redirected to admin login page, which also works fine.

The problem is I don't know how I can redirect the user to admin control panel when he's logged in.

```
app.get('/admin', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/admin.html');
});

app.post('/admin', function (req, res) {

    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {

        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;

    });

    res.redirect('/acp'); // the problem

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`signInWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword) returns a promise:

```js
app.post('/admin', function (req, res, next) {

    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    firebase.auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(function(user) { res.redirect('/acp'); })
        .catch(next);
});
```

Comment: No worries. Also, your use of the Firebase API's auth methods is a little curious. It appears that you will only be able to have a single, signed-in admin and if there is a signed-in admin, it appears that anyone will be able to access an admin route. If you haven't given that consideration, now might be a good time to have a think about it.

Comment: You're right. I just checked on my phone and I can access to admin control panel. What's the best way to do this? Can you give me a link or explain by editing your post above? Just a bit.

Comment: That's a more complicated question, but the simplest solution would be to require an email/password for each admin-related request and perform a signin and siginout in each request handler. That is, don't leave the server signed in as the admin.

Comment: You really saved my life. ;)